# Migrating from WAS to Widlfly how to add binding from XMI file in wildfly server

Tags: wildfly

We are trying to migrate from IBM WAS to Wildfly server. 
Below is my ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xmi file. Where should this binding content be added in Wildfly for listener ports to be active again.

```
<ejbbnd:EJBJarBinding xmi:version="2.0"
xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:ejb="ejb.xmi"
xmlns:ejbbnd="ejbbnd.xmi" xmi:id="EJBJarBinding_1224270065671">  
<ejbJar href="META-INF/ejb-jar.xml#ejb-jar_ID"/>   <ejbBindings
xmi:type="ejbbnd:MessageDrivenBeanBinding"
xmi:id="MessageDrivenBeanBinding_1224270068888"
InputPortName="Listener">
    <enterpriseBean xmi:type="ejb:MessageDriven" href="META-INF/ejb-jar.xml#Listener"/>   </ejbBindings>   <ejbBindings
xmi:type="ejbbnd:MessageDrivenBeanBinding"
xmi:id="MessageDrivenBeanBinding_1260374215550"
InputPortName="ListenerEvent">
    <enterpriseBean xmi:type="ejb:MessageDriven" href="META-INF/ejb-jar.xml#Listener2"/>   </ejbBindings>  
<ejbBindings xmi:type="ejbbnd:MessageDrivenBeanBinding"
xmi:id="MessageDrivenBeanBinding_1267212139948"
InputPortName="ListenerUsrEvent">
    <enterpriseBean xmi:type="ejb:MessageDriven" href="META-INF/ejb-jar.xml#Listener3"/>   </ejbBindings>
</ejbbnd:EJBJarBinding>
```

Answer (score 0):

We changed the binding as well in the standalone XML along with changes to the MQ listener jars.